# Can you take a "free object interaction" while incapacitated?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, conditions

The [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) condition description (PHB 290) says:

> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

Meaning that you can still move. But what about "interactions"?

[Page 190 of the PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn) describes examples you can do "in tandem with your movement and action", it also mentions, "You can interact with one object of feature in your environment for free".

It seems that an "Interaction" is distinctly different from an "Action" or a "Reaction".

Are you still allowed to do (one) interaction on your turn when incapacitated?

Comment: Related: [If you are incapacitated, can you move?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124662/33707)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You can interact with an object by merely using movement

The Basic Rules (and the Player's Handbook section you reference) specify:

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, **during either your move or your action.**

Since the Incapacitated condition only says:

> An incapacitated creature can’t take actions or reactions.

You can still move, and therefore interact with an object or the environment **when you do so**.

### Usually an incapacitated creature can't move anyway

Do note, however, that the most common cause of the Incapacitated condition is through other conditions like Unconscious:

> An unconscious creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can’t move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings

and Paralyzed:

> A paralyzed creature is incapacitated (see the condition) and can’t move or speak.

and Petrified:

> The creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can’t move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings.

and Stunned:

> A stunned creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can’t move, and can speak only falteringly.

In these instances, as you can't move *or* take actions, you would be unable to interact with an object or with a feature of the environment.

Comment: The _Tasha's hideous laughter_ and _symbol_ (pain) spells cause one to be Incapacitated, but do not take away movement. Those are the only times that happens that I am aware of.

Comment: @DavidCoffron therefore, if you don't (but can) move and don't take action, you can not interact with an object?

Comment: @enkryptor correct. The free object/environment interaction necessitates "during either your move or your action"

Comment: Of course if you aren't taking a different action, you could usually just take the Use an Object action.

Comment: @enkryptor "On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed. You can use as much or as little of your speed as you like" - I would say that a move of zero (or call it a millimeter, if you must) can be included in "as little as you like", and allows an object interaction.

Comment: @FooBar why this restriction is necessary, in the first place?

Comment: @mdrichey The torpor poison also causes the incapacitated condition and doesn't affect movement.