# Can you use your free object interaction while restrained?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, conditions

If a character is restrained, like being in the gullet of a froghemoth, and they attempt to pull out a different weapon, I assume they could drop what they were holding, but since their speed is zero, can they pull out another item for free?

For instance, a character drops a dagger and pulls out a magical wand to use.  If they used the dagger, I can see that it was in their hands and the disadvantage imposed would be the crap windup in the stomach of a monster.  Can they simply drop the weapon and pull out the wand for free?

Comment: Related: [Is dropping a weapon "free"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70237/48793)

Comment: Related: "[Can you take a "free object interaction" while incapacitated?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143494)"

Answer (score 21):

### RAW, you can

being *restrained* does not prevent you from using free object interaction

### however

depending on how the restrained condition is being applied, the DM is within their right to apply additional restriction or requirement **to fit the narrative**.

For example, if you are restrained because a guard bound around your arms with rope, it makes sense if you can't draw your wand or weapon, or do so after successfully pass a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check.

Answer (score 9):

### [Restrained](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Restrained) only does what it says

It affects your speed, gives advantage to attack rolls against you, gives disadvantage to attack rolls you make and Dexterity saving throws you make.

That’s it, that’s all, there ain’t no more.

Anything else you could do unrestrained you can do restrained. If you can use your free object interaction while unrestrained (and you generally can), you can use it restrained.

Answer (score 8):

### "A creature's speed becomes 0" doesn't mean it stays motionless

> since their speed is zero, can they pull out another item for free?

"Speed" is a game term here — it means the special number you can see in a stats block. It comes into play when a creature changes its location, see "[Movement and Position](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition)":

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed.

So you can't willingly change your tactical position (move out of your square, if you're playing on grid) while being restrained.

You also expend movement when the rules says so, like when [being prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BeingProne):

> Standing up takes more effort; doing so costs an amount of movement equal to half your speed.

But interacting with an object doesn't cost movement, so you can do it while restrained.

Answer (score 4):

### You can use your free object interaction whilst Restrained

As [Dale M's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/174165/35259) points out, the [Restrained](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Restrained) condition says nothing about restricting your action economy, so you are able to use your free object interaction just like if you were not Restrained.

This is unlike, say, the *[slow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow)* spell, which does restrict what you can do on your turn (although the *slow* spell only makes you choose between an Action or Bonus Action, and still doesn't take away your free object interaction, but this is just an example of a rule explicitly limiting your action economy).

I will also point out that you're not really drawing the wand "for free", since you are using your one and only "free object interaction" to do so, which, despite the name, isn't really free as you can only do it once (otherwise, you wouldn't have to drop the dagger, you could stow it instead). But that's just a nit-pick. As Rykara points out in a comment via a related Q&A, [dropping a weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70237/35259) is "free".

Answer (score 4):

### The free object interaction requires you to either move or take an action; you cannot move, so you must take an action of some sort during which you can use your free object interaction

The Object Interaction rules state (emphasis mine):

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, **during either your move or your action.**

So we must either be moving or taking an action to use a free object Interaction. This idea is also expressed in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/143496) to a question about Incapacitated and the object interaction. We can't move, so we must take an action. In fact, we could even take the Use an Object action and get two object interactions on that same turn.

In this case, you would be taking the Use Magic Device action and could draw the wand as a part of that action.

However, if one had a speed of 0 and was Incapacitated, they could not use their free object interaction as they could neither move nor take an action.