# Are victims of the spell Stinking Cloud able to move out of it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

The pertinent part of the spell description for [*Stinking Cloud*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/stinking-cloud) that has me curious is:

> Each creature that is completely within the cloud at the start of its
>   turn must make a Constitution saving throw against poison. On a failed
>   save, the creature spends its action that turn retching and reeling.

Now, obviously the creatures will need to fail their save in order to be affected. And, also obviously, their action is consumed with *"retching and reeling."* But what about their movement?

**Are victims of the spell *Stinking Cloud* able to move out of it?**

Comment: Action and movement are two different things. Why do you think it affects movement?

Comment: It seems like the description implies incapacitation.

Comment: Related: [If you are incapacitated, can you move?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124662/)

Comment: Excellent related link @enkryptor, TY. Wish I'd found that before asking this question!!

Comment: @lucasvw Please don't answer, even partially, in comments. [We try not to do that here.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## They can leave the cloud

In simple terms, if the spell had limited the creatures ability to move, it would have said so or given a condition which said so. As it stands it only forces the use of actions, leaving bonus actions, reactions, and movement free to use as normal.

Comment: Unless they're unconscious. LIke my poor wizard. RIP.

Comment: @NautArch While that I sympathise, that's isn't the clouds fault. Unconscious creatures aren't able to retch either, which you may well consider a blessing.

Comment: No drowning induced by sleep retching? Good to know!